# Any tool which can identify insertion of codes within a patch after applying the patch

Tags: patch

Is there any tool (command-line) or method which identify modification of an applied patch in a source file?
e.g. -

1. Insertion of new code within the patch
2. Changing the variable or function names within the patch

I know patch utility provides the feature to identify whether a patch is applied or not but I want to go a step further to identify if the applied patch is modified or not ?

Consider the original patch below -

```
  /* stack overflow, return an error */  
-    if (*pStackPtr >= CDL_STACK_SIZE)  
+    if (*pStackPtr >= (CDL_STACK_SIZE - 1)) {  
+        ALOGE("b/34031018, stackPtr(%d)", *pStackPtr);  
+        android_errorWriteLog(0x534e4554, "34031018");  
             return EAS_ERROR_FILE_FORMAT;  
+    }
```

Someone does modify this patch as below -

```
     /* stack overflow, return an error */  
-    if (*pStackPtr >= CDL_STACK_SIZE)  
     int stksize =  *pStackPtr;  // or something like this  
+    if (stksize >= (CDL_STACK_SIZE - 1)) {    
+        ALOGE("b/34031018, stackPtr(%d)", stksize);  
+        android_errorWriteLog(0x534e4554, "34031018");  
             return EAS_ERROR_FILE_FORMAT;  
+    }
```

I have the patched source (may be modified like above) at my local team, original patch and actual patched source file received from the open source repository.
Now; I want to detect with any automation tool (or command sequence) that the original patch is applied but it has been modified a little. I do not want to manually analyze it, as the patches are so many for various open sources and it consumes lot of time and kindly presume that I am asking this question on the forum after exhausting all other options of telling or convincing people to do not modify the original patch.

Comment: So you want to know if the patch is patched?

Comment: Where is the patch coming from (from a source code repository)? Are you afraid it has been tempered with? Can the person that supplied you with the patch help verify it (maybe by means of an MD5 checksum)?

Comment: Just use `diff` on the two versions to see the difference?  There are too many possibilities.  Could you [edit] your question and provide some more info on the use case?

Comment: Don't add clarifying information in _comments_, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: You can use diff, to produce a diff file, or kdiff3 to view it in a more visual way. I think kdiff3 can take a patch file as input. So no need to apply the patch.

Comment: Look into [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) and its *semantic patches*